# Mongodb - How can I write a Push Upsert in c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I would like to implement the following command through c#. I've seen the Update.PushAll command but I'm not sure it's the right way. Any suggestion?

```
db.students.update(
   { name: "joe" },
   { $push: { scores: { $each: [ 90, 92, 85 ] } } }
, upsert = true
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PushAllWrapped` to add an array of scores to your existing document:

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<Student>("students");
var query = Query<Product>.EQ(p => p.Name, "joe");
var push = Update<Student>.PushAllWrapped<int>(p => p.Scores, newScores);
collection.Update(query, push, UpdateFlags.Multi);
```

Using the new syntax, you can achieve using `PushEach`:

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<Student>("students");
var filter = Builders<Students>.Filter.Eq("name", "joe");
var update = Builders<Students>.Update.PushEach<Score>(x=>x.Scores, scores);
await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the legacy syntax? Do you know also how to implement it with the new syntax?

Comment: I extended my answer to include the new syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot! and compliments for your preparation